# How to re-direct to a print template using Knockout js

Tags: templates, knockout.js, printing

I'm using templates in my view and I'd like to direct the user to a print template. Common usage:

`<div data-bind="template: { name: 'print' }"></div>`

but I want this script to appear alone and not with other content.
Is it possible to go to my print script instead of pulling the script into a div, which is what the code above does. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could put a boolean around the "normal" content that hides everything else whenever the print template is active.
  `<div data-bind="visible: noprint()">main site</div>`
- Redirect to a different file that holds the print layout with its own styling.
- Create your page as such that the print-css actually renders the page as expected. Make sure the print styles are always at the bottom of your css

  `@media print {
    body {
      color: #000;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
  }`
- A bit more advanced is working with components, you could use the same data for displaying everything you need but when the user expects a printable view just switch out the screenlayout-component to the printlayout-component

  `<a href="#" data-bind="click: () => layoutType = 'screenlayout'">screen</a>
  <a href="#" data-bind="click: () => layoutType = 'printlayout'">print</a>
  <div data-bind="component: layoutType"></div>`

Comment: Thanks Sam. I like the "visible" approach. I ended doing something similar to your last suggestion using conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing...

```js
var viewModel = {
    selectedTemplate: ko.observable('ViewContent'),

    subTemplate: function (item) {
        this.selectedTemplate(item);
    },

    goBack: function () {
        this.selectedTemplate('ViewContent');
    },

    printLandscape: function () {
        this.selectedTemplate('PrintContent');
        alert("Please change page orientation to Landscape");
        javascript: window.print();
    },
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
.print {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 900px; /* or width: 9.5in; */
    height: 670px; /* height: 7in; */
    clear: both;
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script id="getContent" type="text/html">
    <!-- ko if: ($root.selectedTemplate() == "ViewContent") -->
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'viewContent' }"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: ($root.selectedTemplate() == "PrintContent") -->
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'printContent' }"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>

<script id="viewContent" type="text/html">
<div>Here's the view or display content</div>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: function () { $root.subTemplate('PrintContent') }">Print</a>
</script>

<script id="printContent" type="text/html">
<div><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.printLandscape">Print</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.goBack">Back</a></div>
<div class="print">Here's the print content</div>
</script>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'getContent' }"></div>
```